# this code is jumping on the else statement

Tags: c#, sql, database-connection

```cs
if (EmployeeID > 0)   
{
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("UPDATE EmployeeInfo SET EmpName = @EmpName, Department = @Department, Designation = @Designation WHERE EID = @ID ", con);
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EID", txtEmpID.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EmpName", txtEmpName.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Department", txtDepart.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Designation ", txtDesign.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", this.EmployeeID);

    con.Open();
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    con.Close();

    MessageBox.Show(
        "Employee information is updated successfully", 
        "Saved",
        MessageBoxButtons.OK,
        MessageBoxIcon.Information);

    getemployeerecords();
    resetfunction();
}
else 
{
    MessageBox.Show(
        "Please select employee to update",
        "Select",
        MessageBoxButtons.OK,
        MessageBoxIcon.Error);
}
```

Comment: Add a dbms tag, and a programming environment tag, to get better attention!

Comment: Your if-else statement "if (EmployeeID > 0) { xxxx } else { xxxx }"
You should check why your employeeID is < 0.